How to describe tilting a 2D signal mathematically?
Title: How to describe tilting a 2D signal mathematically?

Hello,
How can I describe the following mathematically?
A 2D signal $f(x, y)$, e.g., an image, is tilted to become $f(ax + by, y)$, and then integrated along the $y$-direction to obtain $r(x)$. This is equivalent to "convolving" the 2D image $f(x, y)$ with a tilted Dirac delta line. Maybe convolution is the wrong word.
How would I write this process in equations?
Thank you!

multiply x,y by the rotation matrix to tilt it. suggest parametrically since it likely wont be a function anymore. i cant help with the convolutions. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ftdysjs9kd

No matter how many words we use, no mathematical descriptioon will automatically make it accurate when we don't know what we are doing. It sounds like you want $$r(x)=\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(ax + by, y),dy,.$$
